# WordPress .htaccess RewriteRule not working

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

Relaunched a website and a lot of old pages need to be redirected to new ones.

I thought this would be simple with htaccess but wordpress has other ideas.
Htaccess's 'Redirect 301' doesn't appear to be supported with all the stuff wordpress does. A lot of forums and posts suggest 'RewriteRule'.

Here is the htaccess code I am working with in the root directory. My code is the two lines starting with 'RewriteBase /'.
I hoped that by going to http://www.example.com.au/skps/contact.html it would redirect me to http://www.example.com.au/about/ .
This just does not work.

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.php

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
#
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^skps/contact.html$‎ http://www.example.com.au/about/ [R=301,L]
#
RewriteBase /digiseen/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /digiseen/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While this doesn't *directly* answer your question, I've had better luck using the [Redirection](http://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/) plugin for this sort of thing.

It's pretty easy to use, and when I'm doing a redesign or changing site structure I use this plugin for a few months (until the search engines have re-indexed the site).  Of course, you can leave it on indefinitely if you wish.

Comment: Jared, I'm thinking your recommendation might be the easiest way. Thanks!